# Live filter in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, filter, laravel-blade

I have a form that looks like below.
I have three "white" dropdowns to filter the value for the Equipment Registration Tag dropdown ( The values of the dropdown input field that has the Equipment Registration Tag label will only come out after the user selects values for the three "white" dropdowns). So the Equipment Registration Tag values will differ based on the "white" dropdowns value.

[image]

I want it to be a live filter, the dropdown options will change immediately every time user selects the "white" dropdown value. Currently, my approach is to use the `onchange=" this.form.submit()"` attribute on the "white" dropdowns and return the values after the filter, but I realize this method has a disadvantage which is a user might accidentally submit the form when changing the value of "white" dropdowns. How can I prevent this and only allow users to submit the form by clicking the save button?

```
    $this->Calibration_Location = $request->get('selected_location');
    $this->Calibration_Category = $request->get('selected_category');
    $this->categories = Equipment::select('Category')->distinct()->get()->toArray();
    $this->locations = Equipment::select('Location')->distinct()->get()->toArray();
    $matchThese = ['Category' => $this->Calibration_Category, 'Location' => $this->Calibration_Location];
    $this->Registration_Select_Tags = Equipment::select('Registration Tag')->distinct()->where($matchThese)->get();
```

I have also tried jQuery, but I can only trigger by a specified dropdown field, not any one of them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var location, category
            $('#selected_transfer_location').change(function() {
                location = $(this).val();
                console.log(location);
                $('#selected_transfer_category').change(function() {
                    category = $(this).val();
                    console.log(category);
                });

                // $('#transfer_registration_tag').find('option').not(':first').remove();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Transaction/' + location + '/' + category,
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        var len = 0;
                        if (response.data != null) {
                            len = response.data.length;
                        }

                        if (len > 0) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                                var id = response.data[i]['Registration Tag'];
                                var name = response.data[i]['Registration Tag'];

                                var option = "<option value='" + id + "'>" + name +
                                    "</option>";

                                $("#transfer_registration_tag").append(option);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            });

        });

    </script>
```

I hope my question is clear, still new to Laravel and I hope could receive some hints from you.

Answer (score 0):

First approach could be that, you use call ajax Query on change of each on of them and fetch filtered results. Something like this:

```
$('#dropdown1, #dropdown2, #dropdown3').change(function(){
    var val1 = $('#dropdown1').val();
    var val2 = $('#dropdown2').val();
    var val3 = $('#dropdown3').val();

    //And then your ajax call here to fetch filtered results.
});
```

Only issue is this Ajax call will occur min 3 times, one for each of them.

Second approach could be you give small button below those dropdowns, something like FetchTags. When user selects all the 3 values, will click on that button and you call your ajax onClick of that btn. So that your Ajax will be called only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/reference) to do that. It  easy.
To install it, you have to use composer by taping the fowllowing command:
`composer req livewire/livewire`

Please check this tutorial to see how to how to do what you want to do using the framework.

Comment: I am curious actually is it a good approach to mix livewire with REST and controllers? ( Still new, sorry if my question is weird )

Comment: I think it is not if you use REST. I am sorry for my first response so. Livewire is useful only under `TALL ` stack (Tailwind Alpine Laravel Livewire)